# How can I extract key-values from one-level JSON string using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression to extract specific keys and values of some `JSON` string.
This is the `JSON` string:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}//there are more key-values
```

And this is the regular expression that I have come up with:

```
^{\s*("([^\"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^\"]+)",?)+\s*}$
```

The problem is that the above-mentioned regex only supports the first set of key-value:

```
{"key1": "value1"}
```

or

```
{"key1": "value1", }
```

With trailing spaces before and after `"value"` and `"key"` but as i mentioned It does not work for more than one key-value pair like this:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

I have added ^{\s*`(`"([^\"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^\"]+)",?`)+`\s*}$     to make the regex support the repetition of the `"key": "value"` pattern in json.
But it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: I am using cpp and for some reasons I do not want to add any external library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you have to,

```
(?<={|,)\s*"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\s*(?=}|,)
```

or,

```
(?<={|,)\s*"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*(?=}|,)
```

or some similar expression might work OK to some extent.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GBnLLV/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yWSLJ2/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/yWSLJ2/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---